# Retrieving extended CSV data from Google Checkout's Order Report API

Tags: csv, google-checkout

The Google Checkout orders page allows you to download the orders data as CSV.  There is a checkbox that allows you to specify that the CSV should include extra data (buyer's name and address, product details).

The Google Checkout [Order Report API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API.html) provides a way to get CSV order data programmatically.  However, it doesn't seem to be possible to get the data in the extended format.  Am I missing something?  Is there some way to specify that you want the full data?

The default data is pretty uninformative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it's not [documented](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Tag_Reference.html#order-list-request), but after a bit of sniffing around and experimenting I discovered that the `<order-list-request>` API method accepts another nested parameter tag, `<column-style>`, and that this should be set to `EXPANDED`.

So a request for the full CSV looks like this:

```
<order-list-request xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2"
                    start-date="2010-08-01T00:00:00"
                    end-date="2010-08-31T23:59:59">
  <date-time-zone>Europe/London</date-time-zone>
  <column-style>EXPANDED</column-style>
</order-list-request>
```

Comment: Is this limited to 5000 orders per day. How do you get more orders?

Comment: @MattAlcock It returns only the most recent 500 within the time period specified but you can re-query with different dates to get earlier orders.

Comment: Sure @DanDyer but what if you have more than 5000 orders a day?

Comment: @MattAlcock Are you saying you can't get more than 5000 orders out of the service in one day of querying, or that you have 5000 orders that were all placed on one day and can't get all of those?  I can get tens of thousands of orders simply by moving the time period backwards and retrying (the responses can be slow so you may need to increase the read timeout). I don't however have 5000 orders on a single day to test that scenario.

Comment: +1. This is a life saver. I was staring to resign myself to wading through the Notification History XML